# Simulator error while adding Firefox OS app to simulator

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-os

I've just developed an app for Firefox OS.But when I opened the simulator and tried to add the app into it; it shows some error code like the following:

The webapp manifest isn't a valid JSON file: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 2 column 24 of the JSON data at: file:///directory.../manifest.webapp

What is the problem?

Comment: are you adding the directory that contains the manifest?  Can you post the manifest?

Comment: Yes in the folder directory there is manifest.webapp file

Comment: {
  "name": "X",

  "description": "XYZ",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",

  "icons": {
            "30":"/img/icon_30.png",
     "60":"/img/icon_60.png",
     "128":"/img/icon_128.png"
    },
  
  "developer": {

    "name": "X",
    "url": "https://www.abcd.com"
  },

  "default_locale": "en"
}

Comment: I found this line in MDN:

"The manifest file should be called manifest.webapp, and be placed in the root of your web app directory alongside your index.html file."

Thats why I keeps the manifest file in that folder along with index.html file.

Comment: remove the semi-colon after "abcd.com"

Answer (score 0):

When having problems with the format of your manifest file, throw it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). When you paste your manifest in there it will highlight the following line:

```
        "url": "abcd.com";
```

With error message:

```
Parse error on line 12:
...   "url": "abcd.com";    },    "defaul
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

So there we have it. Need to be replaced by a `,`.